# Update fancyBox margin on window resize

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Re: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

I’ve set the option for a custom margin but want to adjust that if the window is below a certain size. Does anyone know if that can be done using the API methods. Although the following won’t work, it gives you an idea of what I’m trying to do:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 1024) $.fancybox.update({margin:18});
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made ​​changes using mediaqueries.

By default fancybox keep in your code:

```
padding: 0
margin: 0
```

And then in your container div popup put your margins or paddings and you play with mediaqueries.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Hi Raul, I couldn’t get that to work. Can you give me an example of where you applied the extra styles to?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem by using the `onUpdate()` callback that fancybox provides and changing the margins there based on the screen width:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({ 
        onUpdate: function () {
            if ($(window).width() < 768) {
                $.fancybox.current.margin = [10,10,10,10];
            } else {
                $.fancybox.current.margin = [30,90,30,90];
            }
        }
    });
});
```